# Phoenix EXRM release Websockets not working

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

I've tried to release my application with EXRM. The whole app is working except for WebSockets which fail to start

This is the error in the browser (Chrome)

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4001/socket/websocket?token=undefined' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

It seems that the variable `token` might be a problem.
When starting with `Mix phoenix.server` it all works great. But released with commands:

```
$ mix deps.get
$ mix compile
$ MIX_ENV=prod mix digest
$ MIX_ENV=prod mix release
$ ./rel/project/bin/project
```

Might it be something regarding some missed steps of me or is it Phoenix related issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that in `prod.exs` configuration file the `url` option is responsible for filtering the websocket connections to allow them only from the domain. Because of that it allows only connections from the set url, but not from any other **including localhost**.

So to test releases locally url has to be set to:

```
url: [host: "127.0.0.1", port: 4001],
```

Comment: Yes, precisely. We must do an origin check so attackers cannot access your websocket from external pages. You should also have seen error reports in your terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Been looking for this missing piece in the puzzle for days.